# Changed behaviour of mysqli_stmt::bind_result in PHP-7.4

Tags: php, mysqli

I dont know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I think someone of the experts on this site may give me a valuable answer.

I recently updated from PHP-7.3 to PHP-7.4 and noticed a behaviour, that I was not expecting.
The following database and script are a minimal example to demonstrate my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'Alice'),(2,'Eve'),(3,'Bob'),(4,'Rick');

CREATE TABLE `user_data` (
  `idUserData` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUserData`),
  KEY `idUser` (`idUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user_data` VALUES (1,1,'likes to read'),(2,3,'plays in a band');
```

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli (HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT idUser, name FROM user');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($idUser, $name);

while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT data FROM user_data WHERE idUser = ?');
    $stmt2->bind_param('i', $idUser);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->store_result();
    $stmt2->bind_result($data);
    $stmt2->fetch();

    print $name . ' => ' . $data . '<br>';
}
?>
```

PHP-7.3 gives me the following output:

```
Alice =>  likes to read
Eve =>
Bob =>  plays in a band
Rick =>
```

In PHP-7.4 I get this output:

```
Alice =>  likes to read
Eve =>  likes to read
Bob =>  plays in a band
Rick =>  plays in a band
```

The `bind_result()` or `fetch()` in the while loop do not clear `$data` on an empty sql result set. It still contains the old value from the previous iteration. In PHP-7.3 and lesser versions, the var was cleared.

So is this intended behaviour or did I stumble upon a bug?

Comment: Side note: the problem aside, you can pull this off through a single joining query instead of looping the results of the first one and then performing *n* queries, depending on the number of results.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is just an example to demontrate the basic problem. You are right, that this specific query can be done better.

Comment: Also - you should prepare the statement once outside any loops and make the bindings to variables at that stage too - just substitute values in the loop

Comment: I tried to prepare the statement outside the loop, but the result is the same. Please dont pay attention to the quality of the code. This is just a quick example

Comment: It does look like the output from php 7.3 is more correct in terms of the data you have entered so could well be an "undocumented feature". Perhaps try `$stmt2->free_result();` in the loop before the loop begins next iteration

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I added ```$stmt2->free_result();``` as the last command in the loop. Unfortunately it does not change the output. ```$data``` is still set in the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was correct. It is a bug.

I created a bug report for this question and it was verified as a regression:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80604